# Task Notification to the User before 1 hour on Due Date if the case status is still not closed

Tags: process-builder, tasks

I have a requirement where I need to notify the user if the case status is not closed before the due date. We are already sending him an email alert before an hour of due date but my client requires the notification should be popped up within Salesforce.

So I thought of creating a task before 1 hour of due date if the case status is not closed so that the user will be able to see the notification when the task is created immediately and can work on that. I started creating an action in process builder and came to know schedule actions will work only when record is created, but not on when record is created or edited.

What would be the best way to make this done. Is any alternative for notifications to be popped up before 1 hour of due date? Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by Workflow rule when the record is created or edited.

Create a scheduled action based on task status and define time 1 hour before Due Date.

In the action, create a task with a due date.